# What are the pros and cons of nested templates vs new interfaces?

Tags: java, generics

I'm using Java 6.

Sometimes I find myself doing something like this.

```
Map<String,List<Integer>> myMap;
```

This is just an example. It can go deeper than that.

What are the pros and cons of creating a new interface and doing this instead?

```
Map<String,NewInterface> myMap;
```

The only thing I see is it's a little more readable. Anything else in terms of performance, modularity, coupling, or *you name it*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, if you have logical operations that are complex around the component List you might want to wrap something around it, just to increase modularity and simplify testing.

But if what you are doing is simple then you might not need it.

You do indicate however that there are more complex cases, so Id say abstract away.

You point out the other benefit of abstracting the sub structures out -- readability.

Readability can be key in large software projects.  It keeps the code clean and makes it easier to maintain.  Its difficult to understand the intention behind huge substructures.  You don't want someone who has to maintain this spending half a day figuring out what you are doing, when the code can be self documenting.

Answer (score 0):

For one, `List<Integer>` would obviously not implement your new interface.  You probably have many places in your code where variables are typed as a `List<Integer>`.  The simple `Map<String, List<Integer>>` would have accomodated those lists immediately, but your interface version requires modifying all those places in your code to instead instantiate some new custom version of `List<Integer>` that also implements your custom interface.

This is only an issue because you chose as an example a JDK class that cannot be modified.  If you are dealing with your own classes that you can freely modify, then abstracting out interfaces is a great approach.  The resulting code is often a lot easier to read because it can help minimize the use of generics wildcards.

Answer (score 0):

Even for a single collection, you should be looking towards introducing an abstraction for it. No surprise that as you OO grow software you need new abstractions.

Against introducing abstractions, it adds extra code. At least in the short term.

A few respectable people take the extreme view that you should go straight for the abstraction, and never return a collection.

Average corporate programmers avoid anything object oriented.

Answer (score 0):

Using a new interface will show you fewer characters on the screen, but it can disrupt scenarios where you actually want the multiple types to be associated.

```
public class Graph<T> {

  private Set<T> nodes;

  private Map<T, List<T>> edges;

}
```

If I had made an interface

```
public interface NodeList implements List<T> {

}
```

It would reduce readability and possibly allow errors as you couldn't guarantee that NodeList in

```
  private Map<T, NodeList> edges;
```

was constructed with the same value of `T` as the Map.  For example:

```
edges = new Map<Cities, NodeList>(new NodeList<States>());
```

which is obviously not what was intended.

Comment: Your NodeList interface has no type parameter, and so cannot be instantiated as NodeList<States>. If it had a type parameter, the signature of edges should bind it to the type parameter T of its Graph class, making the mismatching construction a compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

You should pretty much always be programming to the most general abstraction that gives you what you need.  If the contents don't need to be ordered, accept a `Map<String, ? extends Collection<Integer>`.  If you don't need to know the size, lookup elements, etc, but just need to be able to iterate over the elements, use a `Map<String, ? extends Iterable<Integer>>`.

Don't make your code less flexible and more coupled by creating an interface that has no meaning.  Verbosity is just the cost of doing business here.  Don't let it force you into a bad design.